# Short description in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, article

I want to display on main page names of articles and short text of articles. Now WP displays full articles and it is big problem for me.

Is there a way to display short text of articles on main page?

Comment: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [more] tag in wordpress (there is even a button in the GUI article editor that says more)

Answer (score 3):

In navigation admin menu, go to `Setting->Reading`, there is an option `For each article in a feed, show`, choose `Summary`.

Hope it helps.